# How to show the page background above a div using another div in a particular shape

Tags: html, css

I have a page with background set to some img.
I have a div(say div_1) at top:50% which is a horizontal black bar of opacity 0.6.
Above that right at left 50% i want to show a div(with some content in it) with white background it is a round cornered box with opacity 0.6 say this as div_2.

I want div_2 to look like it is directly on page background with no effect from div_1.
may be it is a little confusing.
Thing is as div_2 is on div_1 and div_2 has transparent background, div_1 is effecting the look of div_2.(as i'm placing white transparent box over black box).
Why not remove div_1 then..? I can not as i want that black strip in the center of the page.

May be i need one of this

> 1)something like reverse of anti clip so that i can cut off the exact part of div_1 where div_2 will be present,so that div_2 looks right on page background with no interference from div_1.
>
> 2)take an extra div(div_3) and show the exact part of page background which is present underneath div_2 and put it over div_1 and then put div_2 so that it look as if it is on  page background.

But I'm unable to get an idea on how to do at least one of those two solutions.
Any other solution is also happily accepted.

EDIT

> Here is the code which I have so far,

```
[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5sDce/)
```

Please check the look and feel of "required" tag which can not be seen in div_2, cause of div_1 behind it,
and i can not make div_1 to float next to div_2 as div_2 is of rounded corner.

> Tried it myself and **SOLVED IT**, if someone needs it, please refer to my answer below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Seeing your code would help answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did after experimenting with most of the things in css.

I made div_1 as parent to div_2 and gave a huge shadow to div_2 which can easily spread all over page, then i gave overflow as hidden to its parent div_1 and fixed its size to the width and height of strip which i need.
what it did is it just showed the shadow of the div_2 in the limited space in a fixed rectangle shape which looks as a black strip behind the div_2 as i need and this time there is no interference of any black strip behind div_2(remember its just a shadow!!).so i have the thing which i need which would work in almost all browsers.
And here is the code if some one needs it in future :)

```
[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/uP8UU/)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are searching for something similar to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/).

Two commonly used operations in computer graphics are clipping and masking. Both operations hide visual portions of an element. If you have worked with SVG or HTML Canvas before, these operations are probably not new for you. Clipping defines the region of an element that is visible. Everything around this region does not get rendered - it gets "clipped". On masking, a mask image is composited with the element, affecting the alpha channel of this element. Portions of a masked element get fully or partially transparent. The new CSS Masking specification aims to bring these two operations to the HTML world.

**Clipping in CSS 2.1**

CSS 2.1 already specified the clip property. This property is limited to rectangular clipping with the rect() function taking four distance arguments for the top, right, bottom and left edges. The annoying part: The clip property applies to absolutely positioned elements exclusively. The property is just ignored on other elements.

CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(10px, 290px, 190px, 10px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="568">
```

[image]

[image]

The clip property is limited to specific elements in SVG as well. This is one reason why the SVG specification added the clip-path property that is adapted by CSS Masking now.

**The clip-path property**

The clip-path property can be applied to all HTML elements, SVG graphic elements and SVG container elements. It either references a  element or one of the basic shapes introduced with CSS Exclusions.

The  element takes any graphical element from SVG and uses them as clipping region. Graphical elements in SVG are , , , , ,  and .  allows combining multiple graphical elements as well. The union of all shapes is then used as clipping region. The following example demonstrates the use of :

CSS:

```
img {
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
```

HTML:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="image.jpg" width="568">
```

Basic shapes on the other hand do not require any SVG markup. They were added to clip-path to provide easy shorthand functions for simple clipping operations.

- rectangle(, , , , , ) defines a
  rectangle, similar to the rect() function of clip, and adds two
  optional radius parameters for rounded rects.
- circle(, , ) defines a simple circle with a center point
  and a radius.
- ellipse(, , , ) defines an ellipse with a center
  point and a horizontal and a vertical radius.
- polygon( ,  , ...,  ) defines a polygon based
  on the passed point list.

The CSS markup can look like the following example:

```
img {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...);
}
```

Clipping can be very useful for the presentation of visual content. The following examples apply different clipping operations to images.

[image]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The updated [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/GWt3T/).
You have two solutions. One the existing scenario and the next one you want as reverse.

You have to use `masking` concept for the same.

The HTML:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#)" />
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img id="a" src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.html5rocks-hrd.appspot.com/www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/xclip1a.png.pagespeed.ic.zv42frgxly.jpg">


        <svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="masking1" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img id="b" src="http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.html5rocks-hrd.appspot.com/www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/xclip1a.png.pagespeed.ic.zv42frgxly.jpg">
```

The CSS:

```
img#a {
  mask: url(#masking);
}

img#b {
  mask: url(#masking1);
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the effort put in by you. But it is exacts opposite to what you showed here is what i need.
Please refer to the edited post.
Thank you.

Comment: I assume that my research has helped you out and now you can put your logic and make your thing work out. ;) - @MohanKrishna

Comment: Sry, but as i stated i need something exactly opposite to this, so waiting for an exact answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Here you go. The solution. http://jsfiddle.net/GWt3T/

FYI, I just used logic from my research and I have achieved what you wanted. Cheers. I have updated the same in my answer. - @MohanKrishna

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the updated answer. - @MohanKrishna

Comment: As a last thing can you please send an image showing the difference which you can find on your screen as i'm unable to find any difference,(i'm using chrome v26.0)

Comment: I just checked it in firefox and understood what you were trying to say, it is exactly what i was searching for, but it can not be obtained in chrome, so may be i need a solution which can work in all major browsers(may exclude I.E)

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, kindly accept by a green tick and upvote. Thank you - @MohanKrishna

Comment: I just checked in chrome. It works. I am using Version 26.0.1410.64 m. - @MohanKrishna

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the answer - @MohanKrishna

Comment: Trust me, I'm using the same exact version of chrome and what i can see is just two set of normal images with no effect which can be found in firefox.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and restart your browser - @MohanKrishna

Comment: I hope you got the solution. kindly accept by a green tick and upvote. Thank you - @MohanKrishna

Comment: Mr Mohan Krishna. I assume you already got a solution and after an elaborate discussion to solve your issues and get what you want, by providing and creating a fiddle of your issue with your solutions neither you have upvoted me neither you have accepted the answer. - @MohanKrishna

Comment: Mr Nathan Lee, As I already said, its was not working in the chrome so i can not accept your answer and use it, as chrome is my foremost aim, and i found an answer which works in most of the browsers as i checked and needed, so I can not do much other than wholeheartedly  thanking your effort.

Comment: As I mentioned last time, with screenshots, it worked in chrome and the same version that you are using, but I did not got either any reply or update regarding what is happening from your end. Its great to know that you got your solutions working so enjoy. - @MohanKrishna

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you what but I don't get why you have div_1 fully under div_2 and not just floating next to it if div_1 it's going to be hidden by div_2. Maybe it will be easier I you post what you have.